# Using GridSearchCV of xgboost with DMatrix

Tags: xgboost

I have some problems when I was practicing how to use xgboost.

As I know, the "DMatrix" is a special internal structure that makes the model run faster.

Here's the problem:

To tune the model, (I guess) GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV are considerable.

With the code below:

```
params = {
        'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
        'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
        'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        'max_depth': [3, 4, 5]
        }    
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X,Y), verbose=3, random_state=1001 )
```

I can also do the cross validation by passing cv. That was great.

However,  it really takes time (almost 40 mins with big data and colab gpu) and I really want to improve it.

After I transform my train data to DMatrix:

```
xgbtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_x, train_y)
```

I'm not knowing what to do next because the `.fit` requires X and y..
How to do that? Or any way to make it faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, so I suspect you may have already found an answer. XGBoost can be tricky to navigate the different options when incorporating CV or parameter tuning.

Instead of using xgb.fit() you can use xgb.train() to utilize the DMatrix object. Additionally, XGB has xgb.cv() for performing a cross validation. I myself am hoping to find an alternative to GridSearchCV, but I don't think there is one. The best method may be to create a loop of xgb.cv() to compare evaluation results and identify the best performing parameters.

XGB has really helpful documentation, you may want to check out[XGB Python Intro: Training](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_intro.html#training) and [Cross Validation Demo](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-python-examples-cross-validation-py)

Answer (score 0):

Try Optuna for hyperparameter tuning of XGBoost, much much faster, and use gpu (tree_method = gpu_hist).  Kaggle has free GPU every week.